# Problems changing metatags

Tags: symfony, twig, home-directory

I'm having problems with a symfony PHP website, I'm not being able to change the meta tags even when I change the .twig files.

My website is www.molduras.com.ar and I'm trying to change the data from my homepage (if I open it with chrome and see the source code it is really different from the base.html.twig. For example it shows Molduras.com.ar" as title when it has to show Molduras ArquiCLASS. I didn't programed/designed this site and I'm not well versed on symfony not PHP design.

If anyone can help, my email is f_terbeck@hotmail.com and it will be really appreciated.

Thanks. Fernando.

Comment: If it's a symfony2 website, you'll need to delete the contents of app/cache for the changes to be visible.

Comment: Maerlyn, that's something I don't know how to do, I'll be trying to find that out (searching here and googling a bit) but if you could give me an idea on how to do that it will be great!

Comment: Delete the contents of the `app/cache` directory (or run `php app/console cache:clear`).